# Is there a better way to highlight a group of <TD> elements, either horizontally or vertically?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to highlight a group of table cells (vertically and horizontally) and I am not sure what the best way is. Ideally I'd also like to add a drop shadow on the outlined group.

This is what I came up with, but it's quite hacky. https://jsfiddle.net/jhxLb6s5/39/

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

td.outline {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

td.outline:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;  
}

td.outline.left:after {
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}

td.outline.middle-horizontal:after {
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 0;
}

td.outline.right:after {
  border-width: 6px 6px 6px 0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I think hacky is the only way to do this, I will have a look at some CSS docs for ya but yeah.

Comment: Does it have to be a table? Seems like it would be easier done on a grid.

Answer (score 0):

## Outline a group of table cells

We can use the [rules of table border conflicts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution) to our advantage and place borders in the right places with a bit of tricky [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) use where we can to reduce the need for extra classes.

To go down the column, across rows, we need to specify the top and bottom cells.

TLDR: Full example at the end.

### The table

#### Highlight in a row

Each cell in the outlined group gets an `.outline` class:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline">elit</td>
    <td class="outline">Quisque</td>
    <td class="outline">nulla</td>
    <td class="outline">massa</td>
    <td>vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Highlight down a column

Each cell in an outlined column group gets and `.outline-y` class. The top cell to be highlight is additionally given `.top` and the bottom celll `.bottom`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline-y top">elit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline-y">elit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline-y bottom">elit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### The CSS

Each outlined cell receives a top bottom and left border:

```
td.outline {
  border-top: solid 5px red;
  border-bottom: solid 5px red;
  border-left: solid 5px red;
}
```

Any outlined cell that is to the right of another outlined cell has its left border removed:

(Read more: [adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator))

```
td.outline + td.outline {
  border-left: none
}
```

The first cell after the last outlined cell has a left border given to it:

(Read more: [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not))

```
td.outline + td:not(.outline) {
  border-left: solid 5px red;
}
```

If an outlined cell is the last in the row, it gets a right border:

```
td.outline:last-child {
  border-right: solid 5px red;
}
```

#### Highlighting down a column across rows

A second class `.outline-y` gives left and right borders:

```
td.outline-y {
  border-left: solid 5px red;
  border-right: solid 5px red;
}
```

Then, the top and bottom have to be identified with classes to give top and bottom borders as needed:

```
td.outline-y.top {
  border-top: solid 5px red;  
}

td.outline-y.bottom {
  border-bottom: solid 5px red;
}
```

### Complete Example

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
}

td.outline {
  border-top: solid 5px red;
  border-bottom: solid 5px red;
  border-left: solid 5px red;
}

td.outline+td.outline {
  border-left: none
}

td.outline+td:not(.outline) {
  border-left: solid 5px red;
}

td.outline:last-child {
  border-right: solid 5px red;
}

td.outline-y.top {
  border-top: solid 5px red;  
}

td.outline-y.bottom {
  border-bottom: solid 5px red;
}


td.outline-y {
  border-left: solid 5px red;
  border-right: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Any combination</h1>
<h2>Example 1</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor</td>
    <td>sit</td>
    <td>amet</td>
    <td>consectetur</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline">elit</td>
    <td class="outline">Quisque</td>
    <td class="outline">nulla</td>
    <td class="outline">massa</td>
    <td>vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td>elit</td>
    <td>Quisque</td>
    <td>nulla</td>
    <td>massa</td>
    <td>vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td class="outline">dolor</td>
    <td>sit</td>
    <td>amet</td>
    <td>consectetur</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td>elit</td>
    <td>Quisque</td>
    <td>nulla</td>
    <td>massa</td>
    <td>vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outline">adipiscing</td>
    <td>elit</td>
    <td>Quisque</td>
    <td>nulla</td>
    <td>massa</td>
    <td class="outline">vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2>Example 3</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem</td>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td class="outline">dolor</td>
    <td>sit</td>
    <td>amet</td>
    <td>consectetur</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outline">adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline">elit</td>
    <td class="outline">Quisque</td>
    <td class="outline">nulla</td>
    <td class="outline">massa</td>
    <td class="outline">vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outline">adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline">elit</td>
    <td>Quisque</td>
    <td class="outline">nulla</td>
    <td>massa</td>
    <td class="outline">vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Example 3 - In a column across rows</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem</td>
    <td class="outline-y top">ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor</td>
    <td>sit</td>
    <td>amet</td>
    <td>consectetur</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline-y">elit</td>
    <td class="outline">Quisque</td>
    <td class="outline">nulla</td>
    <td class="outline">massa</td>
    <td class="outline">vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>adipiscing</td>
    <td class="outline-y bottom">elit</td>
    <td>Quisque</td>
    <td>nulla</td>
    <td>massa</td>
    <td>vestibulum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem in my Chrome (V104 on Windows). And I'd be surprised if there were any long standing Chrome bugs in table rendering, as Chrome's table rendering was completely re-written fairly recently.

Comment: @Alohci - ha, that's good to know. It bugged out in Codepen which is when I took the screenshots, but I can't recreate so must have just been a rendering issue in Codepen itself. I've removed that bug section from my answer.